# floor plan scanned image to screen pixels adjustment

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution, pixel

I am trying to develop a windows form based application in c#. The form has an image control and it has a scanned image of a floor plan. I get the x and y coordinates from the user of the real floor and I want to draw a small circle exactly on the same location on the image. This is showing the location of a user on the map.

The problem is that we can not equate the real world coordinates to screen pixels. So we need to get a formula for adjustment. Is there any formula for adjustment or we do it by trial and error. Also if we somehow adjust the conversion it will be based on the current screen resolution. Is there any formula for adjustment which caters for different screen resolution so that we can run the application on any screen size with any resolution.

Comment: is WPF an option for you? you can VERY easily do this in WPF.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not, the application is already developed and I am just adding some functionality to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my understanding you have a problem with some lacking coordinate understanding.
In the real world we think a coordinate plane as the lines X and Y forming 4 Quadrants.

On the computer you only work on the 1st quadrant and it's upside down meaning that origo (0,0) is your top left corner.

so to convert if you don't want to do it in your head

```
public int computerX(int realWorldX)
{
    return realWorldX+(int)(ImageControl.Width/2);
}

public int computerY(int realWorldY)
{
    int Convert = realWorldY+(int)(ImageControl.Height/2);
    int Flip = ImageControl.Height - Convert;
    return Flip;
}
```

when you placed realworld (1,1) you used some other cordinate in the program from the looks of it 25,25, you could just multiply so if you want realworld 2,2 then write 50,50 like this

```
public int computerX(int realWorldX)
{
    return (realWorldX+(int)(ImageControl.Width/2))*yourXOffset;
}

public int computerY(int realWorldY)
{
    int Convert = realWorldY+(int)(ImageControl.Height/2);
    int Flip = ImageControl.Height - Convert;
    return Flip*yourYOffset;
}
```

Comment: The real world coordinates are also in the inverted first quadrant. So my real world 0,0 is on the top left. The problem here is related to scaling I think. The 1,1 in the real world does not coincide with the 1,1 pixel of the image on the screen.

Comment: so where is (1,1) exactly? Image of your problem would be great

Comment: if its an image you could make it into a bitmap and use graphics

Comment: And the two circles are on (0,0) and (1,1), I whould like to see it on 0,0 1,1 2,2 and 3,3 to see how it escalates

Comment: Do you draw on the image or on the imageControl? meaning do you draw on the bitmap or do you create two and overlay.

Comment: The first circle is at (1,1) of the image, but the 2nd is showing the real world (1,1) on the image. What I want to be able to have the first circle mapped to the 2nd.

Comment: I have one bitmap and I am drawing in Paint() method.